# Excel JS API - Custom Functions Refresh Disables Excel Undo

Tags: excel, office-js, custom-functions-excel

We are using the Excel JS API custom formulas to build reports for our users. We found that users cannot undo changes like they can in any standard Excel file. It looks like any calls to the Excel API clears the undo stack.

This is very tough feature to take away from Excel users. Is there any fix for this currently or upcoming? It could be a deal breaker for the API.

Comment: It is doubtful that this will change, vba has done this from the beginning.

Comment: I think it's totally resonable that doing most things in the API should clear the 'undo stack'. But I guess the custom functions are pretty unique. A change to those causing the stack to clear is tough to work around.

Comment: Through the years with vba, there have been many suggested work arounds.  None that I like, as it literally requires one to make multiple copies of the sheet before each run of the code so one can replace the current with the correct version.

Comment: So our Users are finding that with the Excel Version 1908 the Undo functionality works! But Users on newer Version of Excel (2002) does not work.

Comment: Rick Kirkham do you know anything about this version difference? I'm surprised the newer version is the problem.

Comment: How you trigger the custom function refresh? are you calling API to refresh the function?

Comment: No this is using the "custom functions api". Not using the Office API either way. Below is an example from the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-web-reqs

Comment: If I may ask, how was user perception without the Undo so far? @RickKirkham, for the suggestion box, could custom functions possibly be declared with a 'compatibility' scope as narrow as (COM) RTD servers, where Undo functionality is preserved? That would probably cover many use cases.